# Vanilla web-component structure

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, html5-template, html5-import

I am looking into structuring vanilla web-components. I have previously used Polymer and like the fact that you can have the template, styles and JavaScript in one file for your component. I want to achieve this with 'vanilla' web components if possible but can't work out how. I've taken the code from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/customelements/#fromtemplate) and added it to a file which I am using as follows:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Component test</title>
    
    <link rel="import" href="x-foo-from-template.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo-from-template></x-foo-from-template>
  </body>
</html>
```

This fails because when we try to select the template it does not exist because at that point the template is not in the DOM (right?).

Is there any way to achieve this? I personally prefer this approach to creating the HTML in the JavaScript using `document.createElement`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 main methods to get the template from the imported document:

**1. From the `import` property of the `<link>` element**

The `<link rel=import>` elements own an [`import`](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/#interface-import) property that contains the imported document.
You can perform a `querySelector` call on it to fetch the `<template>`:

```
var doc = document.querySelector( 'link[href$="x-foo-from-template.html"]').import
var template = doc.querySelector( 'template' )
```

Then import the template in the custom element (or in its Shadow DOM) using either `importNode()` or `cloneNode()`.

---

**2. From the `ownerDocument` property of `currentScript`**

When a script is parsed, the global value [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) references the script being parsed, and therefore its propery `ownerDocument` is a reference to the document that owns the script. You can perform a `querySelector` call on it:

```
var template = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector( 'template' )
```

*Note:* the `currentScript` value is set **temporarily**, so it won't work any more in subsequent calls, like `connectedCallback()` or `attachedCallback()`, so you'll have to memorize it in a persistent variable at parse time, to reuse it later when needed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Shame I can't do it exactly how I want but this will do!

Comment: What do you want exactly? Maybe I could improve my answer.

Comment: A note, if you're using `<script type="module">` the only non-hacky way to do it is #1 from above as document.currentScript is null per the spec.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old answer, but why wouldn't `document.querySelector( 'template' )` be the same as `document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector( 'template' )`?

Answer (score 0):

For latecomers:

### As of 2021, HTML imports feature has been deprecated ([MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports)).

I would not recommend it, you can instead: create a template tag with a data- attribute to html imports. Write a script that runs on all those elements with that attribute and access those html parts using `fetch()` in the script, add that fetched import to the template tag and use it eg: `template.content.cloneNode( true )`.