# How to get ownerDocument of a custom element B which is child of another custom element A

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I have a custom element A as "main" element and a custom element b that I have included in A. 
Now I added the template code in custom element b to itself by calling

```
  // var currentOwner = document.currentScript.ownerDocument; // doesn't work
  const tmp = currentOwner.querySelector('#b4-toggle-button');
  this.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
```

I'm consfused why i have to determine my currentOwner variable outside the class to get the proper reference of `ownerDocument` while within the class i will get the reference of custom element A...

Can someone explain me this case please?

Here is the working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/fGOwdGqBXFRZCbYIUBCZ

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39588365/4600982 and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41409299/4600982

Comment: thanks a lot bro, that helps.