# How to get reference to a markup element in an import html file in web components?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am using web components and I have this code

codea.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Component</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />

        <!-- load your library web component -->
        <link rel="import" href="codeb.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- load by tag -->
        <script>
            const cls = customElements.get('dom-element');
            var element = new cls();
            document.body.appendChild(element);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

codeb.html

```
<template id="x-foo-from-template">

</template>

<script>
    customElements.define('dom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
            //const t = document.querySelector('#x-foo-from-template');
            //const t = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#x-foo-from-template');
            const instance = t.content.cloneNode(true);
            shadowRoot.appendChild(instance);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Where I define `t` in the second script, the second `t`, works if I put `<dom-element></dom-element>` in the `codea.html`. But if I try to put it in with JavaScript code like what I have, both `t` attempts don't work. They get null.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: or this one [Vanilla web-component structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39576933/4600982)