# What is "document.currentScript" and "ownerDocument"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component, html5-template

I am learning Web Components. To grab a template, I needed to do this:

```
<template>
  <div>The sky is blue</div>
</template>

<script>
    var tmpl = (document.currentScript||document._currentScript).ownerDocument.querySelector('template');
```

Instead of:

```
var tmpl = document.querySelector('template');
```

I don't understand this part at all: `(document.currentScript||document._currentScript).ownerDocument`

What is `currentScript`, what is `ownerDocument`? What is the purpose? Why does it work. Note that the template code I have shown above gets pulled in via the `link` element.

Note, this is related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419562/create-and-use-a-custom-html-component/47419631?noredirect=1#47419631) and this [article](https://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/). I AM just trying to understand the keywords, I don't have any particular problem in mind.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/10i4xmn/comment/j5d5mlr/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition taken from here:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-currentscript

> `document.currentScript`
>
> Returns the script element, or the SVG script element, that is **currently executing**, as long as the element represents a classic script. In the case of reentrant script execution, returns the one that most recently started executing amongst those that have not yet finished executing.
>
> Returns `null` if the Document is not currently executing a script or SVG script element (e.g., because the running script is an event handler, or a timeout), or if the currently executing script or SVG script element represents a module script.

And I believe that `_currentScript` comes from a Polyfill.

The `ownerDocument` for anything in the DOM Tree will be `document` but for a `<template>` or a file loaded through an HTML Import the `ownerDocument` will be a different document. This is why `document.querySelector()` won't work to get the `<template>` of a file loaded using an HTML Import.

Comment: I am able to use `_currentScript` without any polyfills in Chrome. I am guessing my code is not even hitting that due to the null coalescing. Regardless, I am still having a hard time following the formal definition.

Comment: All I know is that I always check both. Maybe I should understand the `why` but once I found how to get it to work, I stopped looking. ;).

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the help, you did get my code up and running =)

Answer (score 3):

`_currentScript` was used in the old [webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) polyfill (version 0.x). Now if you use polyfill version 1.x it is always `undefined`.

You should then use only `document.currentScript`:

```
<template>
  <div>The sky is blue</div>
</template>

<script>
    var tmpl = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('template');
</script>
```

`document.currentScript.ownerDocument` will give you a reference to the imported document (with `<link rel='import'>`), where the current `<script>` is running and where the `<template>` is defined.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39588365/4600982) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41409299/4600982)) for further details on this topic.